# How can is send textView Value From One active to other in android?

Tags: android, string, onbackpressed

I am building an android application Where on click of an Image-view the OnBackPressed Function is called.

Here is code -

```
    ImageView imgv = (ImageView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.back);

    imgv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Now The Problem is how To send an Text-View String With this OnBackPressed function.

Comment: What about using a public static String variable in the activity class?

Comment: @Morad How can i Do this please tell me

Comment: use `putExtras` and `getExtras` in a Bundle

Answer (score 3):

When you want to start second activity use this code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

When you want to come back to first activity use this code :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

And finally in the first activity you can get the returned value by the following method :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // If there is no result 
        }
    }
}
```

---

**AN EXAMPLE :**

So for using the above code for developing the example that you said :

in forst activity start second activity :

```
public void ButtonClickedMethod(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}
```

then in the on back pressed method of second activity use this code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).getText());
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Again on the first activity use this code :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setText(result);
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // If there is no result 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Might you understand wrong. Let me More clear. In First Activity There is an Button my click on it I move to Second Activity now In Second Activity There is an TextView and an ImageView on Click of ImageView I again go to Firstactivity. now In first activity button text should be change find the parse value of text

Comment: @Sonam The code is OK ,just you should use it for doing your development , I edited the answer and added the example of using the code , This is the code that you need in your application , This code will open second activity and when you press back button on the first activity button text will change to textView that exists on second activity , Feel free to ask your questions ;)

Comment: Thanks I am doing this in onBackPressed Funtion for checking really my value is parsing or not by toasting the value. But the toast value is null. here is my code - String arg = null;
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra(arg, txtmapinfo.getText());
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg,
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg,              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); should be before the finish() method not after it.